# Java RDF libraries for Google App Engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, rdf

Are there any Java libraries available that allow RDF processing on the Google App Engine?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Jena](https://jena.apache.org/) on Google App Engine with a few minor modifications. Taylor Cowan summarised his findings in a [post to the Jena support list](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/jena-dev/message/39575).